# How to make a triangle using a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to programming and have been experimenting with for loops to try and figure out how to make different shapes however I have encountered a problem that I cannot solve.

So far I have been able to create a rectangle of 1's as shown below in a 5X5

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  X = 0
  for j in range(0, 5):    
  X = (X*10)+1
  print(X)
```

I would like to be able to modify this code using a for loop to be able to create a triangle like so...

```
1 1 1
1 1
1
```

How would I go about doing this? Is there also a way that I could input n and dependant on whatever number is input the program creates a triangle of that size? for example I input a 5 and it creates a triangle like...

```
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

Ive tried various different things but i'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: How about `for j in range(0, 5-i):`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def triangle(c, n):
    for i in xrange(n, 0, -1):
        print c * i

triangle("X", 5)
```

prints:

```
XXXXX
XXXX
XXX
XX
X
```

Answer (score 0):

don't try to modify it.
make a new one

```
def generateLine(size):
    line = ""
    for i in range(0, size):
        line = line+"1"
    return line

for i in range(6, 0):
    print generateLine(i)
```