# Python Logic - decreasing set of 1's using for loops to create triangle

Tags: python, for-loop

This is for a [CS101 type Python class](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/7c-loops/).

The problem asks the programmer to write for loops which will set up this pattern:

```
111
11
1
```

I have example code here which produces

```
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111

for i in range(0, 5):
  X = 0
  for j in range(0, 5):
    X = (X*10)+1
  print(X)
```

Here's one of my attempts. Obviously it doesn't work. Please help!

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
  X = 0
  for j in range(0, n):
    X = (X*10)+1
    i=(n-2)
  print(X)
```

Please try to explain an answer using loops only. We haven't gotten to functions. I have [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075662/how-to-make-a-triangle-using-a-for-loop-in-python) but it is written as a function.

Comment: When you say "using only loops" have you also covered the `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the current `i` index from the maximum length to know how many `1`s you should have per line:

```
for i in range(n):
    X = 0
    for j in range(n-i):
        X = X * 10 + 1
    print X
```

Comment: Paulo I understand now. The teacher wrote back and said this is what he was looking for. He wanted to emphasize that you can modify an inner for loop by using the outer loop (0,n-i)

Answer (score 5):

You can use loop that goes `n to 1`, backwards (3,2,1 in this case):

```
n = 3
c = "1"

for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(c * i)
```

or the same with a while loop:

```
n = 3
c = "1"

i = n
while i != 0:
    print(c * i)
    i -= 1
```

both snippets print:

```
111
11
1
```

You are seeing "111" instead of 3, because `c` is a string, and python has this magical thing that I call "string breeding" - if multiply a string with an `n` integer, string  repeats `n` times:

```
>>> s = "1"
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> s * 2
'11'
>>> s * 10
'1111111111'
```

`-1` in range function call is a value of a `step` argument. If step is negative, looping goes backwards, from the end to the beginning of the range:

```
>>> range(0, 10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(10, 0, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Note: replace `range` with `xrange` if you are on Python 2.

Hope I've explained it well.

UPD: simplified version:

```
n = 3

while n != 0:
    number = 0
    for i in range(n):
        number += 10 ** i

    print number
    n -= 1
```

Comment: Can you explain (n,0,-1)? Also, how does c*i not = 3*1?

Comment: @StacyM check the updated answer. I've tried to make the explanation simple.

Comment: How come you don't get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' error?

Comment: Well, you can get this error if try to multiply strings, for example: `"1" * "1"`. In the answer, I'm multiplying string and integer - this is pretty much ok in python.

Comment: Thanks they haven't taught this yet.

Comment: alec, I really doubt the professor was expecting us to come up with the use of the -1 reverse range concept and the "string-breeding". Just curious, any other answers using just for loops and math?

Comment: @StacyM see simplified version. Works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach you have using integers.  All you need is a length variable that starts at 3 (or whatever) and counts down to 1.  The for loop for that using range is:

```
for length in range(3,0,-1):
    X = 0
    for j in range(length):
        X = 10*X + 1
    print (X)
```

The third argument to range() is an increment value to be added to the previous value to produce new values until the stop value is reached or passed.  This defaults to 1, but you can use other values to count by twos, count backward, etc.

Note that range(length) is the same as range(0, length).

I just now figured out what you were trying to do with that i=(n-2) assignment.  This isn't a C-like language where you can modify the number of iterations by changing the for-loop variable.  The number of loops and set of values is fully determined before the first iteration of the loop, and you can't change that within the loop.  All you can do is end the loop early with a break or return statement.

To get a feel for looping with range, start up Idle or Python interactive mode and just print out a some range() values.

Comment: They haven't explained this syntax yet (3,0,-1): Can you clarify what the , -1 means?

Comment: Your second to last paragraph is not entirely correct, you can change the number of iterations within the loop. For instance, you can do `for` on a list and pop from the list.

Comment: Mike, as I asked alec, can you do this without the -1 reverse range concept? I don't think the professor would have expected us to use something that wasn't taught yet.

Comment: @StacyM, my answer is similar and uses forward ranges (the indentation was wrong initially). And you have other solutions using `while` now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses a list that is mutated with a while loop and uses the str.join() method, which avoids concatenation.

```
n = 5
l = ['1'] * n

while l:
    print(''.join(l))
    l.pop()
```

To explain the magic here, the list `l` contains `n` "1" strings. When you loop `while l`, it will continue looping until the list is "Falsy" (empty). `''.join(l)` takes all of the strings in the list `l` and joins them together, inserting the string `''` (empty) between them. Then, `l.pop()` removes the last item from the list (and returns it if you want it).

Answer (score 0):

Python also has`while`loops:

```
n = int(input())
while n > 0:
  X = 0
  for j in range(0, n):
    X = (X*10) + 1
    i = n - 2
  print(X)
  n -= 1
```

Sample output (for n=5):

```
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution, (and maybe what your teacher is getting it) is to use pythons builtins to do the work for you.

```
for number in reversed(range(10)):
    print number*"1"
```

### explanation

range(n) - creates a sequence of numbers from 0 to one less than n.

e.g. range(n) -> [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]

reversed() - flips whatever you pass it.

e.g. reversed([1, 2, 3]) -> [3, 2, 1]

Python treats multiplying an int by a string as "repeat me".
so we use use range to generate the number of repeats necessary in each row, and we use reverse to flip so the pyramid starts big and shrinks.

Remember to choose n to be one larger than the width of the first row of "1"s

Answer (score 0):

n=int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
  X = 0
  for j in range(0, n-i):
    X = (X*10)+1
  print(X)